# Use Java Properties in Freemarker

Tags: java, multilingual, freemarker

HI,

I have a typical `messages.properties` file in my application.
I'm trying to generate an email using Freemarker.

The Freemarker template should generate to a `String`, after which I'll send the `String` to the user via email. However, we need it multilingual.
So `Properties` came to mind.

My properties file looks like this:

```
mail.layout.contactus=Contacteer ons
mail.layout.greeting=Hoi
```

In Java, I enter the `Properties` file in my `HashMap` like this:

```
rootMap.put("lang", (mail.getLanguage().equals(Language.FRENCH) ? langFR : langNL));
```

And try to read it in FreeMarker like this:

```
<p>${lang.mail.layout.greeting} ${user.firstname},</p>
```

But get following exception:

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression lang.mail is undefined on line 10, column 116 in layout/email.ftl.
```

Strangely, it only says `lang.mail` as opposed to `lang.mail.layout.greeting`

**Edit:**
I tried defining my keys like this:

```
mail_layout_contactus=Contacteer ons
mail_layout_greeting=Hoi
```

which does work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem is that with a key of `lang.mail.layout.greeting`, Freemarker treats each part between the `.`s as a [hash](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/dgui_quickstart_datamodel.html) i.e. a container variable that can have *subvariables*. So it attempts to get the object referenced by `lang` from the data-model and then attempts to get the variable referenced by `mail` from `lang`. In your case, however, there is no such object, hence the error.

[The documentation has this to say about variable names](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/dgui_template_exp.html):

> In this expression the variable name can contain only letters (including non-Latin letters), digits (including non-Latin digits), underline (_), dollar ($), at sign (@) and hash (#). Furthermore, the name must not start with digit.

You might make use of the [alternative syntax to get data from a hash](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_var_hash) (as long as the expression evaluates to a string)

```
<p>${lang["mail.layout.greeting"]} ${user.firstname},</p>
```