# how do I set Freemarker global variable in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I have a Spring MVC 4.2.x application.  I want to use Freemarker as my view resolver. I currently have .jsp's  and in them, at the base of all url's is this code:

```
src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/TrademarkedLogo.png"
```

My question is how do I do this for freemarker?  I know I can add that to the model every time I call a controller,  but I obviously don't want to do that if I don't have to.  There is the setSharedVariable(name,value)  in the configuration,  but in spring, you cant set 2 variables in a context.xml.

Any Ideas?

Comment: do you want something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249205/how-to-get-the-request-context-in-a-freemaker-template-in-spring)?

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of broad suggestions... you could perhaps put the value that's meant to go there in a properties file and get it out of that - there is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020126/use-java-properties-in-freemarker). Or you could do things the AOP way and add `@AfterAdvice` which adds that property to the model, so you never have to declare it manually but it just gets added automatically after each call to a controller method.